# Help with XML parsing in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have a XML file which contains 100s of documents inside . Each  block looks like this:

```
<DOC>
<DOCNO> FR940104-2-00001 </DOCNO>
<PARENT> FR940104-2-00001 </PARENT>
<TEXT>

<!-- PJG FTAG 4703 -->

<!-- PJG STAG 4703 -->

<!-- PJG ITAG l=90 g=1 f=1 -->

<!-- PJG /ITAG -->

<!-- PJG ITAG l=90 g=1 f=4 -->
Federal Register
<!-- PJG /ITAG -->

<!-- PJG ITAG l=90 g=1 f=1 -->
 / Vol. 59, No. 2 / Tuesday, January 4, 1994 / Notices
<!-- PJG 0012 frnewline -->

<!-- PJG /ITAG -->

<!-- PJG ITAG l=01 g=1 f=1 -->
Vol. 59, No. 2
<!-- PJG 0012 frnewline -->

<!-- PJG /ITAG -->

<!-- PJG ITAG l=02 g=1 f=1 -->
Tuesday, January 4, 1994
<!-- PJG 0012 frnewline -->

<!-- PJG 0012 frnewline -->

<!-- PJG /ITAG -->

<!-- PJG /STAG -->

<!-- PJG /FTAG -->
</TEXT>
</DOC>
```

I want load this XML doc into a dictionary `Text`. Key as DOCNO & Value as text inside  tags. Also this text should not contain all the comments. Example  `Text['FR940104-2-00001']` must contain `Federal Register / Vol. 59, No. 2 / Tuesday, January 4, 1994 / Notices Vol. 59, No. 2 Tuesday, January 4, 1994`. This is the code I wrote.

```
L = doc.getElementsByTagName("DOCNO")
for node2 in L:
    for node3 in node2.childNodes:
        if node3.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE:            
            docno.append(node3.data);
        #print node2.data
L = doc.getElementsByTagName("TEXT")
i = 0
for node2 in L:
    for node3 in node2.childNodes:
        if node3.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE:
            Text[docno[i]] = node3.data
    i = i+1
```

Surprisingly, with my code I'm getting Text['FR940104-2-00001'] as `u'\n'` How come?? How to get what I want

Comment: your question is not very clear

Comment: @t00ny: improved my question.

Answer (score 4):

You could avoid looping through the doc twice by using [xml.sax.handler](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.handler.html#contenthandler-objects):

```
import xml.sax.handler
import collections


class DocBuilder(xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.state=''
        self.docno=''
        self.text=collections.defaultdict(list)
    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        self.state=name
    def endElement(self, name):
        if name==u'TEXT':
            self.docno=''
    def characters(self,content):        
        content=content.strip()
        if content:
            if self.state==u'DOCNO':
                self.docno+=content
            elif self.state==u'TEXT':
                if content:
                    self.text[self.docno].append(content)


with open('test.xml') as f:
    data=f.read()            
builder = DocBuilder()
xml.sax.parseString(data, builder)
for key,value in builder.text.iteritems():
    print('{k}: {v}'.format(k=key,v=' '.join(value)))
# FR940104-2-00001: Federal Register / Vol. 59, No. 2 / Tuesday, January 4, 1994 / Notices Vol. 59, No. 2 Tuesday, January 4, 1994
```

Comment: can we use lxml for SAX parser, or how lxml.sax differs from xml.sax ?

Comment: @Tumbleweed: Yes, one could use lxml.sax.saxify instead. The syntax is almost exactly the same as for xml.sax, though you'd have to change `startElement` to `startElementNS` since lxml.sax supports namespace-aware processing only. See http://codespeak.net/lxml/sax.html

Comment: @Tumbleweed: Another option would be to use `lxml.etree.iterparse` or `lxml.etree.XMLParser` with a custom target. See Liza Daly's excellent article http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/#ibm-pcon for an example of how to do fast iterative parsing without building an entire parse tree in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to unutbu's answer, though I think simpler:

```
from lxml import etree
with open('test.xml') as f:
    doc=etree.parse(f)

result={}
for elm in doc.xpath("/DOC[DOCNO]"):
    key = elm.xpath("DOCNO")[0].text.strip()
    value = "".join(t.strip() for t in elm.xpath("TEXT/text()") if t.strip())
    result[key] = value
```

The XPath that finds the `DOC` element in this example needs to be changed to be appropriate for your real document - e.g. if there's a single top-level element that all the `DOC` elements are children of, you'd change it to `/*/DOC`.  The predicate on that XPath skips any `DOC` element that doesn't have a `DOCNO` child, which would otherwise cause an exception when setting the key.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think your version is not only simpler, it also (unlike my now deleted lxml-based answer) correctly handles adjacent `DOCNO` s with no `TEXT` in between.

Comment: +1 for [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml). Much better than python's xml support in the standard library.

Comment: @unutbu: it actually doesn't handle adjacent `DOCNO`s at all.  It finds `DOC` elements that have at least one `DOCNO` child.  For each, it looks in the first `DOCNO` element to find the key.  If there are multiple `DOCNO`s, it ignores all but the first.  Also, if there are multiple `TEXT` children, it concatenates their text nodes together.

Comment: Suppose the xml had more than one pair of DOCNO and TEXT nodes. Do you see a way to modify your code to handle this case?

Answer (score 1):

Using [lxml](http://lxml.de/):

```
import lxml.etree as le
with open('test.xml') as f:
    doc=le.parse(f)

texts={}
for docno in doc.xpath('DOCNO'):
    docno_text=docno.text.strip()    
    text=' '.join([t.strip() 
          for t in  docno.xpath('following-sibling::TEXT[1]/text()')
          if t.strip()])
    texts[docno.text]=text

print(texts)
# {'FR940104-2-00001': 'Federal Register / Vol. 59, No. 2 / Tuesday, January 4, 1994 / Notices Vol. 59, No. 2 Tuesday, January 4, 1994'}
```

This version is a tad simpler than my first lxml solution.
It handles multiple instances of DOCNO, TEXT nodes.
The DOCNO/TEXT nodes should alternate, but in any case, the DOCNO is associated with the closest TEXT node that follows it.

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
Text[docno[i]] = node3.data
```

replaces the value of the mapping instead of appending the new one. Your `<TEXT>` node has both text and comment children, interleaved with each other.

Answer (score 0):

DOM parser strips out the comments automatically for you. Each line is a Node.

So, You need to use:

`Text[docno[i]]+= node3.data` but before that you need to have an empty dictionary with all the keys. So, you can add `Text[node3.data] = '';` in your first block of code.

So, your code becomes:

```
L = doc.getElementsByTagName("DOCNO")
for node2 in L:
    for node3 in node2.childNodes:
        if node3.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE:            
            docno.append(node3.data);
            Text[node3.data] = '';
        #print node2.data

L = doc.getElementsByTagName("TEXT")
i = 0
for node2 in L:
    for node3 in node2.childNodes:
        if node3.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE:
            Text[docno[i]]+= node3.data
    i = i+1
```